Estimate of a series
I want help to estimate the series
$$S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^2}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k}\right)^{-k}.$$
Clearly this series converges and since the sequence $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k}\right)^{-k}$ decreases, then
$$S\ge \dfrac{\pi^2}{6e}.$$
When I put this series on the computer it's giving a little bit more than 3/4. I need help to prove that $S\ge \dfrac34$ is actually true. Any hint/help will be helpful. Thank you !!

What kind of proof do you need?  If you take a subset of terms and add them together, getting something greater than 3/4, then you've proved that the series is greater than 3/4 (since all terms are positive).

$$\frac{3}{4} < \sum_{k=1}^{20} \frac{1}{k^2} \left(1 + \frac{1}{k} \right)^{-k} < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} \left(1 + \frac{1}{k} \right)^{-k}$$
